# Why I'm getting different responses when i use urllib.request.urlopen and requests.get

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

Why I'm getting different responses when i use urllib.request.urlopen and requests.get

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/14/Sunset_Boulevard_%281950_poster%29.jpg')
r.status_code
```

response 403

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
r = urlopen('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/14/Sunset_Boulevard_%281950_poster%29.jpg')
r.getcode()
```

response 200

Comment: If you look at the content of the 403 response... you'll see *Error: 403, Forbidden. Please comply with the User-Agent policy [...]*

Comment: @Jon That policy: https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy

Comment: I don't get a response 200 when I run your urllib request- I get a SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Comment: I don't know what header `User-Agent` sends `urllib` but `requests` sends something like `python-requests/2.26` - and this can be used to block script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you could check `print( r.content )` to see what you get from server.
Usually you can get some explanation which can help to see problem.

---

For your code it shows problem with header `User-Agent`

Wikipedia: [User-Agent policy](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy)

Some servers check header `User-Agent` to send different content for different systems/browsers/devices. They use it also to detect scripts/bots/spamers/hackers and block them.

If I use header from real browser (or at least short `Mozilla/5.0`) then it works.

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/14/Sunset_Boulevard_(1950_poster).jpg'
#url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/14/Sunset_Boulevard_%281950_poster%29.jpg'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.content[:100])

with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(r.content)
```

---

**EDIT:**

After running code few times it start working for me even without `User-Agent`. Maybe they checked it for some different reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but why the "urllib" worked without needing the headers

Comment: `urllib` uses different value in header `User-Agent` and for this portal it may looks like correct header. `requests` is very popular and maybe they add its header on blacklist but they didn't add header from `urllib`

Comment: after running few times it start working even without `User-Agent` - maybe there remebere me (or my IP) or server saw that I run it only few requests - so it start accept my requests even without `User-Agent`